Trim/ Extend tool -- doesn't snap to intended feature
I have been using the trim/ extend tool to connect service lateral lines to water mains, or so I thought. Upon further investigation, when zoomed in as far as possible, it turns out these two features were not snapped together and a small space existed between the two.
Are there any settings that can be adjusted so that the trim/ extend tool would result in these two features being snapped together?

How small is small? Coordinates are finite and have a minimum division, the only way to ensure an actual connection is to insert a vertex on the water main at the coordinate of the service lateral line end. Is this actually causing a problem? Network and geoprocessing tools are aware of this limitation and will take it into account in their operation.

That's what I was thinking, but when I mentioned that maybe "close was close enough to count," I was immediately shut-down like it was dumb of me to think that. We were zoomed in to the 1:0 scale and it was a very tiny gap (like, .00004 ft). I also thought a vertex insertion might help, so thanks for boosting my confidence that maybe I do sometimes know what I am talking about, lol.
